# PayPal Checkout directly using the Braintree SDK - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, checkout, braintree

I'm trying to integrate PayPal on my IOS app. first I tried [PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) but it's deprecated and not accepted by Apple because of using UIWebView on it. So I tried to integrate using Braintree but my country not supported yet. I don't have any options but to use Checkout through Braintree. I checked this [page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/) but it didn't help me at all. I need docs or tutorials on server side and how I will add access token from PayPal on Braintree server code.

If you tried integrate PayPal checkout through Braintree **Please Help Me**
Or guide me with better way to integrate PayPal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've linked to the correct guide.

You'll also need resources from https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview , although you won't be integrating Braintree Direct or the Drop In UI -- just PayPal.

The credentials you will use for sandbox development will be from the bottom of  https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications (Log into dashboard then scroll to bottom), and later for live they will be in https://www.paypal.com/api

You'll be using the Braintree SDK on iOS, but you also need a webservice to generate the nonce. All of this is covered in the guides.

Comment: webservice asking for merchantId, publicKey and privateKey. Can't find any guide to make webservice using paypal access token instead keys from braintree account

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/#2-set-up-your-server-to-call-the-braintree-sdk ??